# Count common elements from pairwise rows with multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, optimization

I want to count the number of common elements between rows (each row has 6 elements/ columns)

My dataframe (df) looks something like this:

```
>>> df
         Customer Number    Most Frequent Called 1    Most Frequent Called 2    Most Frequent Called 3    Most Frequent Called 4    Most Frequent Called 5
    0    552711620          161359852                 611336215                 884140437                 804548991                 135953430
    1    561712520          186359312                 666336115                 855140357                 899548041                 134953530
    2    331112180          316659812                 436926115                 545220357                 117748041                 984213530
    3    873212120          196357673                 331112180                 565777359                 174348053                 554212940
    4    113219540          733352993                 975632166                 569117345                 175888077                 364212923
   ...
```

I have tried this code:

```
connection_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df)):
    connection_list = []
    for j in range(len(df)):
        intersection = set(df.iloc[i]).intersection(df.iloc[j])
        connection_list.append(len(intersection))
    connection_df.insert(loc=i, column = str(i), value = connection_list)
```

This will give me a dataframe of a form of a matrix like this:

```
>>> connection_df
         0    1    2    3    4
    0    6    0    0    0    0
    1    0    6    0    0    0
    2    0    0    6    1    0
    3    0    0    1    6    0
    4    0    0    0    0    6
```

This piece of code does what I want, but as I'm using loops, they are very inefficient. Potentially there will be millions of rows so I want to ask for any suggestions on optimizing these codes. Thanks.

Comment: What is the logic for generating the new dataframe?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Hi, the connection_df is for seeing which customers have connections with each other. For eg: customer 2 and customer 3 share 1 most frequent called number so that means they are connected.

Comment: How many row do you have? You want to create a dataframe of size `row x row` which seems huge if `row` is quite big. Furthermore, do you plan to add more column or 6 is fixed?

Comment: @JérômeRichard My ultimate goal is to see which customer has relationship/ connection with which customer. That connection_df is not really neccesary but for now that's the only soluition I've got. Let's assume it is fixed at 6 columns. If you have any ideas please share :D Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient solution consist in **performing all the operation with Numpy** (by converting the whole dataframe to a Numpy matrix), **computing only the upper part of the matrix** as the intersection between two sets is *symmetric*, and **pre-computing all the sets**.

```py
def fastConnectionDf(df):
    size = len(df)
    connection_mat = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.int)
    df_mat = df.to_numpy()
    uniqueSets = [np.unique(df_mat[i]) for i in range(size)] # Precompute all the sets
    for i in range(size):
        connection_mat[i,i] = len(uniqueSets[i])
        for j in range(i+1, size):
            intersection = np.intersect1d(uniqueSets[i], uniqueSets[j], assume_unique=True)
            connection_mat[i,j] = len(intersection)
    connection_mat = np.maximum(connection_mat, connection_mat.T)
    connection_df = pd.DataFrame(connection_mat)
    return connection_df
```

On my machine, this solution is **28 times faster** on the example dataframe (and up to 50 times faster on bigger dataframes).

---

Note that it is possible to improve the algorithm by:

- just counting the number of intersecting elements rather than creating an array with all the items
- using a more clever implementation can sort the arrays before to speed up the set intersections (see `np.searchsorted`)
- using **Numba** to speed up the computation on big dataframes

The two first improvements are hard (impossible?) to perform efficiently only with Numpy, but possible with Numba although this is a bit complex to do.